# migrating spring boot version 2.7.3 to spring-boot 3.0.0 so existing code is breaking related EntityManagerfactory is not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, java-17

Error: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument

Using Spring boot 3.0.2 the hibernate-core version 6.1.6.Final

Dependencies are.:

```
junitVersion=4.13.1
awsSDKVersion=1.11+
testPostgresVersion=1.15.0
jacocoVersion=0.8.7
guavaVersion=31.1-jre
servicePort=80
version=22.1.0
serviceName=Test
postgresJdbcVersion=42.4.1
hibernateVersion=6.1.6.Final
secretsManagerJdbcVersion=1.0.5
secretsManagerCacheVersion=1.0.1
flywayVersion=6.4.3
jakartaVersion=3.1.0
httpclient5=5.2.1

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'idea'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.2' apply false
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'com.test.gradle.minion-application' version '5.+'
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "${jacocoVersion}"
}

mainClassName='com.test.modelgenerator.ModelGeneratorApplication'

minion {
    maintainer='test-team@incontact.com'
    baseImage='111111111.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/workbench-base-java17:2-1.0.0'
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '7.6'
}

jar {
    enabled=true
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
    }
}

configurations.all {
    // check for updates every build
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1"
    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1"
    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api:2.17.1"
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.17.1'
   
    implementation 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry'
    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"){
        exclude group : 'org.yaml' , module : 'snakeyaml'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-aspects'
   
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:${awsSDKVersion}"
    implementation ("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:${awsSDKVersion}"){
        exclude group : 'org.yaml' , module : 'snakeyaml'
    }
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ssm:${awsSDKVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:${guavaVersion}"
    implementation "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:${flywayVersion}"
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.7'
    //  For assuming role in local dev mode
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:${awsSDKVersion}"
    implementation "com.amazonaws.secretsmanager:aws-secretsmanager-jdbc:${secretsManagerJdbcVersion}"
    implementation "com.amazonaws.secretsmanager:aws-secretsmanager-caching-java:${secretsManagerCacheVersion}"
    implementation "org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgresJdbcVersion}"
    //implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:${hibernateVersion}"
    implementation "jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:${jakartaVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:${httpclient5}"
    testImplementation "cloud.localstack:localstack-utils:${localStackUtilsVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:postgresql:${testPostgresVersion}"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:${junitVersion}"
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
        exclude group : 'org.yaml' , module : 'snakeyaml'
    }
}
```

Comment: Before answering I assume you read the upgrade guide? Also you are trying very hard to work around the Spring Boot dependency management.